# SQLite Difficulty Retrieving a Value from a Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? The table that I am querying is empty, so I think that the cursor should be empty. But instead, it returns a cursor with 1 row and 1 column. Even so, I don't see why this results in an error. All I am trying to do is return the single value (if it exists) from my query.

Can somebody help me understand this? Thank you!

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT max(GAME_COLUMN) FROM GAMES_TABLE", null); 
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     System.err.println("why am I here?");
     nextGame = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("GAME_COLUMN"));
}
```

> Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no column named GAME_COLUMN in the result. Make your query

```
SELECT max(GAME_COLUMN) AS GC FROM GAMES_TABLE
```

and then query for GC :-

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT max(GAME_COLUMN) AS GC FROM GAMES_TABLE", null); 
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    System.err.println("why am I here?");
    nextGame = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("GC"));
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. I'm just learning this SQL stuff, so I"m doing lots of wheel spinning. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks again!